# How can I access the text property to split it at every colon?

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I wonder why this code snippet in javascript does not work. How can I access the text property?

```
lst = [{"antwort1" : {"text": [{"text": "hallo1, hallo2"}]}}, "antwort2"];

text = lst[0].antwort1.text.text.split(",")
```

Thank you very much for helping

Comment: Since inner `text` is also an array . Hence try `lst[0].antwort1.text[0].text.split(",")`

Answer (score 1):

It is a simple error of forgetting to index an array. Your approach does not throw an error due to the text method of strings.

```
lst[0].antwort1.text[0].text.split(",")
```